# Unit test and live run giving different XML parse results

Tags: xml, vb.net, unit-testing

I have a class which looks like this:

```
Public Class TestResult
    Public Sub New(labelName As String, correctValues As List(Of Object))
        Me.LabelName = labelName
        Me.SelectedValues = correctValues
    End Sub

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub
    Public Property LabelName As String
    Public Property SelectedValues As List(Of Object)
End Class
```

I'm trying to parse XML into a `List(Of TestResult)`.

The thing is, is that depending on the type of execution(test or live), I get different results each time. With the live run giving me the expected results.

Here is the function which parses the XML into a `List(Of TestResult)`

```
  Public Function ReturnTestValidResults(testID As String) As IEnumerable(Of TestResult) Implements ITestManager.ReturnTestValidResults
        Dim testValidResults = ReturnSingleRepComplianceFieldViaTestID("TestValidResults", testID)

        Dim serializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(List(Of TestResult)))

        Dim result As List(Of TestResult)

        Using reader = New StringReader(testValidResults)
            result = serializer.Deserialize(reader)
        End Using
        Return result
    End Function
```

Here is the XML:

```
<ArrayOfTestResult xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <TestResult>
    <LabelName>Question1Label</LabelName>
    <SelectedValues>
      <anyType xsi:type="xsd:int">2</anyType>
    </SelectedValues>
  </TestResult>
  <TestResult>
    <LabelName>Question2Label</LabelName>
    <SelectedValues>
      <anyType xsi:type="xsd:int">2</anyType>
    </SelectedValues>
  </TestResult>
  <TestResult>
    <LabelName>Question3Label</LabelName>
    <SelectedValues>
      <anyType xsi:type="xsd:int">3</anyType>
    </SelectedValues>
  </TestResult>
  <TestResult>
    <LabelName>Question4Label</LabelName>
    <SelectedValues>
      <anyType xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</anyType>
    </SelectedValues>
  </TestResult>
</ArrayOfTestResult>
```

When running the code from a unit test it correct parses into the `List(Of TestResult)`

But the `SelectedValues` property contains a list of the XML type and the value. Whereas live is just the value.

Here is an example:

Unit test result:

```
{Attribute, Name="xsi:type", Value="xsd:Int"}
{Text, Value="2"}
```

Live:

```
{2}
```

The only thing I could possibly see why this is happening is because I've had to put the XML in my unit test with double quotes to stop it from escaping the string.

Here is my unit test code:

```
 <TestMethod()> Public Async Function CheckSubmittedResults_SubmittedLabelsAreCorrect_ActionReturnsPassedJsonResult() As Task
        Dim testController = New TestController(_iTestManager, _ihomeManager, _iGeneralACManager)
        Dim submittedResults = New List(Of TestResult)
        Dim validResults = New List(Of TestResult)
        submittedResults.Add(New TestResult("Question1Label", New List(Of Object)() From {2}))
        submittedResults.Add(New TestResult("Question2Label", New List(Of Object)() From {2}))
        submittedResults.Add(New TestResult("Question3Label", New List(Of Object)() From {3}))
        submittedResults.Add(New TestResult("Question4Label", New List(Of Object)() From {True}))

#Region "HugeXMLString"
        Dim testResults = $"<ArrayOfTestResult xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema""><TestResult><LabelName>Question1Label</LabelName><SelectedValues><anyType xsi:type=""xsd:Int"">2</anyType></SelectedValues></TestResult><TestResult><LabelName>Question2Label</LabelName><SelectedValues><anyType xsi:type=""xsd: Int"">2</anyType></SelectedValues></TestResult><TestResult><LabelName>Question3Label</LabelName><SelectedValues><anyType xsi:type=""xsd: Int"">3</anyType></SelectedValues></TestResult><TestResult><LabelName>Question4Label</LabelName><SelectedValues><anyType xsi:type=""xsd: Boolean"">true</anyType></SelectedValues></TestResult></ArrayOfTestResult>"
#End Region

        _iTestRepository.Setup(Function(x) x.ReturnSingleRepComplianceFieldViaTestID("TestValidResults", Nothing)).Returns(testResults)

        Dim result = Await testController.CompleteTest(submittedResults, Nothing)

        Assert.IsTrue(result.Data.Success = True, "Action should have passed.")
```

Can anyone see why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced test results in unit test with this

```
Dim testResults = String.Format("<ArrayOfTestResult xmlns:xsi='{0}' xmlns:xsd='{1}'><TestResult><LabelName>Question1Label</LabelName><SelectedValues><anyType xsi:type='{2}'>2</anyType></SelectedValues></TestResult><TestResult><LabelName>Question2Label</LabelName><SelectedValues><anyType xsi:type='{3}'>2</anyType></SelectedValues></TestResult><TestResult><LabelName>Question3Label</LabelName><SelectedValues><anyType xsi:type='{4}'>3</anyType></SelectedValues></TestResult><TestResult><LabelName>Question4Label</LabelName><SelectedValues><anyType xsi:type='{5}'>true</anyType></SelectedValues></TestResult></ArrayOfTestResult>",
                                        "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "xsd:int", "xsd:int", "xsd:int", "xsd:boolean")
```

Turns out it was the double quotes, I got around it by using string format with single quotes.